# SQL Server statement with subselect is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, ibatis, subquery

Hey, I am using iBATIS with SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 and try to do a subselect

```
INSERT INTO FORMINSTANCE (ID, ID_FORM) 
  SELECT #ID#, f.ID 
  FROM FORM f 
  WHERE ID_PROCESS='10804'
```

When I commit the transaction I get an `SqlCeException` (`SSCE_M_QP_PARAMETERNOTALLOWED`).

That the Symbol '`@`' is on the wrong place. I think this is the #ID# which is unpredicted in `SELECT`. #ID# is not the name of the column, it's the value that should be inserted into FORMINSTANCE How can i fix this?

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the # part of the column name…

```
INSERT INTO FORMINSTANCE (ID, ID_FORM) 
SELECT [#ID#], f.ID 
FROM   FORM f 
WHERE  ID_PROCESS='10804'
```

If for some odd reason you wanted a dynamic column to be selected at position #1 (not that I really think that this is what you're up to, but anyway), you could get away with:

```
INSERT INTO FORMINSTANCE (ID, ID_FORM) 
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN @ID = 'foo' THEN foo
    WHEN @ID = 'bar' THEN bar
    ELSE NULL
  END, 
  f.ID 
FROM
  FORM f 
WHERE
  ID_PROCESS='10804'
```

Comment: #ID# is not the name of the column, it's the value that should be inserted into FORMINSTANCE

Comment: Then it's a string and should be denoted as `'#ID#'`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes if i try it with, it works: INSERT INTO FORMINSTANCE (ID, ID_FORM) 
SELECT 'UUUID', f.ID FROM FORM f WHERE ID_PROCESS='10804'

Comment: Hm, if you "try it with" *what*? :) (Does that mean it actually works now?)

Comment: Yes ah sorry, i meant the SELECT 'UUUID', thought you would see it. It seems to works with '$ID$'. But i don't like that, sql injection & co. :(

Comment: Hm, so '#ID#' is a placeholder for a *real* value in iBATIS? Because to T-SQL it does not have a special meaning (AFAIK), and you should go with *actual* @-parameters instead of string expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can if #ID# isn't in the FORM table (ie, a parameter). Even if #ID# was in the standard parameter format of @ID, SQL Server CE doesn't support named parameters in that location.

Comment: Hmm then maybe my subselect is wrong structured? But it works if i don't use the named parameters and try instead of #ID#  -> 'UUID'. Than the insert works.